# C# Web scraper copying text

Tags: c#, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

I have a web scraper written in C# for extracting data. I want to copy text from the web browser control and paste it into a Word file programmatically. When I try to extract rich text box content using its ID and InnerText, the text contains encoded characters like %2c.

I need to get the text with all formatting but I can't find any way. I have tried `Encoding`, `HTTPUtility.UrlDecode`, `SendKeys` and `elem.InvokeMember()` without success.

How can I programmatically copy and paste text from web browser control preserving formatting?

Here is the sample data to extract:

**Description**

The Advance Concepts Engineering team designs and develops new vehicles which will meet future regulatory requirements and customer competitive requirements. A qualified candidate will be responsible for the total vehicle packaging. The candidate will identify and resolve adaptation and packaging issues as the vehicle moves toward production. They will lead cross functional team meetings working with Systems & Components, Advance Manufacturing, Service, etc. to ensure that the solutions are optimized for all stages of the vehicle's life.

```
HtmlElement elem = wb.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_contplhDynamic_txtDescrContentHiddenTextarea");
                if (elem == null) return;
                elem.InvokeMember("Click");
                //elem.InvokeMember("Select All");
                //elem.InvokeMember("Copy");
                SendKeys.SendWait("^a");
                SendKeys.SendWait("^c");

                Clipboard.Clear();
                elem.Focus();
                elem.InvokeMember("Right Click");
                elem.InvokeMember("Select All");
                elem.InvokeMember("Copy");

                Clipboard.SetText(elem.InnerText);
                string clipbrdText = Clipboard.GetText();

                string data = elem.InnerText;

                richTextBox1.Text = data;
                string temp = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data);

                Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252");
                Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
                byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(data);
                byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
                string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: No Ivan, I coudn't. I would have liked to copy the text and paste it to any word doc or anywhere to save it. But i cannot copy the text. Manually I can copy, but its of no use. Do you find some way ?

Answer (score 0):

The text with "%2c" etc has been encoded.  If you are getting the content of a web page, you are decoding the HTML, not the URL.  You can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`, or if you are using .NET 4.0 or above you can also use WebUtility.HtmlDecode - this is available within the `System.Net` namespace.

You should note that Word does not use HTML for its formatting, so you won't be able to paste HTML tags and expect it to recognise them.  i.e. `<strong>Description</strong>` will not result in bold text if you type that into Word.

**EDIT:**

It looks like you are mixing two different ways to copy the text in the code you pasted - both `SendKeys.SendWait("^c");` and `elem.InvokeMember("Copy");`.  I presume both of these methods work?

I think the problem you are having lies in the way you are getting the text. I see you're using `Clipboard.GetText()` to get the text.  Try specifying that it is **formatted** text using `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)` or `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)`. This should hopefully copy the string preserving the formatting.

Comment: Thanks Ivan for the reply. I searched for the formatting issue. Therefore I am trying to copy and paste text. When I copy and paste from my web browser like chrome or even from web browser control and paste it to word the formatting remains intact. So I am trying to find a way to programmatically copy and paste text. Any help regarding that functionality would be very helpful too.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your program inserts the HTML into the Windows clipboard (a programmatic copy) and then you are pressing Ctrl-V and pasting the text into the document, but it lacks formatting and has HTML tags instead?

Comment: No. I used SendKeys("^C") like code on the element but it copies nothing. I cannot get any way to copy the text and then paste it. Currently I am using just element.innertext and also tried HTTPUtility.HtmlDecode but to no avail

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post your code? It would make it easier to see what is going on.